# Using mousewheel with jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('#myDiv')
    .bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
        var dir = delta > 0 ? 'Up' : 'Down',
        vel = Math.abs(delta);
        alert(dir + ' at a velocity of ' + vel);
        return false;
    });
});
```

I have some problem with getting the mousewheel to work. 
I have the following code in my head section:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
```

I copied the function from another web page, and added the alert. But nothing happens. Why? There might be some obvious mistake that I can´t see with my jQuery beginner eyes.

Comment: it works for me, if write it independently instead of inside `jQuery(function($) {});`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jsFiddle of your code working : http://jsfiddle.net/ykv5S/ (tested on firefox 19.0.2)

```
$('#myDiv')
    .bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
        var dir = delta > 0 ? 'Up' : 'Down',
        vel = Math.abs(delta);
        alert(dir + ' at a velocity of ' + vel);
        return false;
    });
```

Please check that jQuery and the mousewheel plugin are both correctly loaded on your page

Comment: Hi BinaryAnnie, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please make sure to describe why your answer is useful to the OP.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to install the jquery-mousewheel plugin.

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/downloads

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to test

```
var delta = 3.45;
var dir = delta > 0 ? 'Up' : 'Down',
        vel = Math.abs(delta);
```

in my js console and it comes back with dir being undefined.  Try changing it to the following:

```
var delta = 3.45;
var dir = delta > 0 ? 'Up' : 'Down';
var vel = Math.abs(delta);
```

if that still doesn't work check the console for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cross-browser solution:

```
var onMouseWheel = function(e) {
    e = e.originalEvent;
    var delta = e.wheelDelta>0||e.detail<0?1:-1;
    alert(delta);
}
$("body").bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", onMouseWheel);
```